# Are "East trading post" and "West trading post" considered identical structures?

Tags: 7-wonders

The rules state that a player can never build two identical structures - with the same name/illustration.

Since both "Trading post" cards are called just "Trading post" on the "Forum" card (which could be build through chain construction), are they considered *identical*, according to the "same name" rule?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The East and West Trading Posts are considered separate structures because they have a different name and illustration. Using the short form on the Forum card indicates that either the East or West Trading Post can be the base for chain construction.